# Disable field validation of custom line items when cart is modified

Tags: forms, commerce

How to disable custom line item's field validation when line item is removed from cart?

My line item has a required field and if product/line item is removed from cart it still tries to validate it.
This causes form errors which isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for this function (since your not giving full information about that custom module you have)

```
function nameOfModule_form_validate(&$form_state, &$form_id){
```

You can search inside that function where it is doing the validation

Comment: Hi! I've debugged this and I believe that this validation is fired from Views module `views_form_views_form_validate`. I can't find any "hooks" to manipulate Views form validation functionality:  [link]https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_form_views_form_validate/7.x-3.x[/link]

Comment: Like I said in my previous answer, I'm sure it has the *$form_id* between "()", then try to catch your $form_id to avoid that validation

Comment: Cart seems to be a Views form which isn't as simple as is basic form manipulation via fapi.